# How to debug a detector test in the IntelliJ idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spotbugs, find-sec-bugs

I'm new to Find-Sec-Bugs (FSB) and want to trace through analysis steps by debugging the HttpParameterPollutionDetectorTest test in the IntelliJ IDE. I've successfully run all tests with maven, but when I start to run/debug the HttpParameterPollutionDetectorTest.detectHttpParameterPollution method in IntelliJ, I get the following error. Can someone point me to a direction to fix it?

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=41943040 -javaagent:/opt/idea-IU-222.3345.118/lib/idea_rt.jar=42285:/opt/idea-IU-222.3345.118/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/idea-IU-222.3345.118/lib/idea_rt.jar:/opt/idea-IU-222.3345.118/plugins/testng/lib/testng-rt.jar:/home/tester/work/find-sec-bugs-v1.12/out/test/test:/home/tester/work/find-sec-bugs-v1.12/out/production/test:/home/tester/work/find-sec-bugs-v1.12/findsecbugs-samples-java/target/test-classes:/home/tester/work/find-sec-bugs-v1.12/findsecbugs-samples-deps/target/classes:/home/tester/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/commons-io-2.11.0.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/javax/jws/javax.jws-api/1.1/javax.jws-api-1.1.jar:/home/tester/work/find-sec-bugs-v1.12/out/production/main:/home/tester/.m2/repository/com/github/spotbugs/spotbugs/4.5.3/spotbugs-4.5.3.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/apache/bcel/bcel/6.5.0/bcel-6.5.0.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/com/github/spotbugs/spotbugs-annotations/4.5.3/spotbugs-annotations-4.5.3.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/9.2/asm-tree-9.2.jar:/home/tester/work/find-sec-bugs-v1.12/findsecbugs-test-util/target/test-classes:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/4.3.1/mockito-core-4.3.1.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.12.7/byte-buddy-1.12.7.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.12.7/byte-buddy-agent-1.12.7.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/3.2/objenesis-3.2.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/2.2/hamcrest-core-2.2.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest/2.2/hamcrest-2.2.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/7.4.0/testng-7.4.0.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/com/beust/jcommander/1.78/jcommander-1.78.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/webjars/jquery/3.5.1/jquery-3.5.1.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.26/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.2/asm-9.2.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.2/asm-analysis-9.2.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/9.2/asm-commons-9.2.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.2/asm-util-9.2.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/net/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/dom4j/dom4j/2.1.3/dom4j-2.1.3.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-text/1.9/commons-text-1.9.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.9/gson-2.8.9.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/jaxen/jaxen/1.2.0/jaxen-1.2.0.jar:/home/tester/.m2/repository/net/sf/saxon/Saxon-HE/10.6/Saxon-HE-10.6.jar com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -usedefaultlisteners false -socket35251 @w@/var/tmp/idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp -temp /var/tmp/idea_testng.tmp
org.testng.TestNGException: 
An error occurred while instantiating class com.h3xstream.findsecbugs.injection.http.HttpParameterPollutionDetectorTest: class org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLogger can not implement org.slf4j.Logger, because it is not an interface (org.slf4j.Logger is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:123)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:25)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:112)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:165)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:122)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:102)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:94)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:59)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:463)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:339)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:292)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:183)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:173)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1300)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1276)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1125)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLogger can not implement org.slf4j.Logger, because it is not an interface (org.slf4j.Logger is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:86)
    at com.h3xstream.findbugs.test.BaseDetectorTest.<clinit>(BaseDetectorTest.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:23)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(InstanceCreator.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:113)
    ... 23 more

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: The issue looks rather like there are incompatible libraries in the classpath. Does deploy work from command line and fails only in IDE? Have you tried using different JDK version?

Comment: My system has JDK 8 and 11.  Whn I used Maven to run the test, and it was OK without an issue. When I use JDK 11, I get the following updated error in IntelliJ, which indicates an slf4j issue (IntelliJ uses an incompatible slf4j from Maven?):

org.testng.TestNGException: 
An error occurred while instantiating class com.h3xstream.findsecbugs.injection.http.HttpParameterPollutionDetectorTest: class org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLogger can not implement org.slf4j.Logger, because it is not an interface (org.slf4j.Logger is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: I cannot put the entire output in comments, so I've updated the original post with the new output.

Comment: I couldn't find the exact cause, but fixed the issue by doing the following: I removed the JetBrain cache under ~/.cache/JetBrains and the .idea directory in the project and reimported the project. Afterward, I can debug it in IntelliJ.